# Search query from search box looking for contenttypeids

Tags: search, search-results, query

{SearchBoxQuery: ContentType:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39007B3838B9BC334FD5A775B8EBEE407D1F0050EECE79DC1D06469A2CB43CE1682F42* }
I am trying to create a search which searches pages with a particular content type, I have use the code above but it doesn't seem to work.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to search simply on the content type ID of an "ITEM" which is 0x01 to see if the search returns any results. 
You can try to search with

> ContentType={content type NAME} OR ContentTypeId:{content type ID}

Refer [this](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/02/14/sharepoint-2013-search-by-content-type-using-query-builder/) link